# Add Canvas Shadow to Particular Text Element Only

Tags: canvas

```
addText: function(opts) {
        opts = opts || {};
        var options = _.extend({}, MEME.TEXT.defaults, opts);
        var text = options.text;

        delete options.text;

        var txt = new fabric.Text(text, options);
        if(document.getElementById('text-shadow').checked) {

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.shadowColor = "black";
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2; 
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2; 
        ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
        }

         if(document.getElementById('text-glow').checked) {

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.shadowColor = "yellow";
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5; 
        ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5; 
        ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
        }

        canvas.add(txt);

        txt.center();

        MEME.objects.text.push(txt);
        MEME.makeSelected();
    },
```

This way its fill the style in all the element .
How I can select that particular text element only.
I am making changes in this script 
Ref: http://demo.mememakerscript.com/generate

Answer (score 0):

Its Resolved Now , 
I used febric shadow class instead canvas 2d. 
Thanks anyway if you seen this.